# Reduce a UIView's Height From the Top Down?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

Resizing a UIView's height can be done by modifying it's `frame.size.height` property OR by modifying it's `NSLayoutHeight` constraint. However, by default, reducing a UIView's height will cut off the UIView from the bottom up, I need to reduce a UIView's height from the top down. Is this possible?

Comment: Did you try setting the [contentMode](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/contentMode) property?

Comment: What do you mean by top down? You want the bottom of the view to stay where it is, and have the top move down? Are you doing an animation?

Answer (score 1):

Adjust the `origin.y` of the view as you change the height.

```
CGFloat const delta = 100;
[aView setFrame:CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX([aView frame]), CGRectGetMinY([aView frame]) + delta, CGRectGetWidth([aView bounds]), CGRectGetHeight([aView bounds]) - delta)];
```

Comment: Perfect answer!

Answer (score 1):

You will need to adjust the origin of the frame as well.

Eg:

```
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 20.0, 40.0)];
```

to change the height to `30.0` from the 'top down' do:

```
view.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 10.0, 20.0, 30.0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create container UIView with clipsToBounds == YES, and move your view inside the container view.
Just like clipping mask in drawing software.